# Insert Rows Variable Times Per Row in Sybase SQLAnywhere 12

Tags: jasper-reports, sqlanywhere

I'm using Jasper Reports to generate labels. This works great. I can generate the labels to a PDF and print them with no trouble. My issue now, is that my application has the functionality to specify how many to print of each.

The way it works right now is I have a procedure that gets all the fields for each item and inserts it into a database, which Jasper Report looks at to get the label information. This inserts one row per item.

I imagine, to print x number of the same label, I'll have to insert the same row x times. Is there a way I can do this in Sybase SQL Anywhere 12 or is there something in Jasper Reports that would let me duplicate a report (Each label is technically a report)?

Summary:
How can I insert each row from a result set a variable number of times each in Sybase SQL Anywhere 12?
For example:

I have these 3 label records in a resultset:

```
pk    name    size    numLabels
_______________________________
1     Water   12oz    2   
2     Coke    16oz    3   
3     Milk    1gal    1
```

I'd like to add each item to my jasper table *numLabels* number of times. So my jasper table would look like this:

```
pk    name    size
__________________
1     Water   12oz
1     Water   12oz
2     Coke    16oz
2     Coke    16oz
2     Coke    16oz
3     Milk    1gal
```

I'm not sure what more information to give, so please feel free to ask for more.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RowGenerator](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbreference/systb-s-4690757.html*d5e68390) system table. Say your first result set is defined in a table called `t1`. Your query would look something like:

```
insert into JasperTable select pk, name, size 
    from t1, dbo.RowGenerator rg
    where rg.row_num <= t1.numLabels
```

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*